# Buffer Power of the amphiprotic substance

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

The mass balance for a generic amphiprotic substance $[\ce{AH^-}]$ this:

$$
[\ce{HA^-}]=C \cdot \dfrac{K_{a1} [\ce{H_3O^+}]}{K_{a1}\cdot [\ce{H_3O^+}] + [\ce{H_3O^+}]^2 + K_{a1} \cdot K_{a2}} \quad Eq.1
$$

where: 
 C = initial concentration of the amphitrofic substance

The Eq.1 derivative  is:

$$
\dfrac{d[\ce{HA^-}]}{d[\ce{H_3O^+}]} = -\dfrac{C \cdot [\ce{H_3O^+}] \cdot K_{a1} \cdot (2 [\ce{H_3O^+}] + K_{a1}}{(K_{a1}\cdot [\ce{H_3O^+}] + [H_3O^+]^2 + K_{a1} \cdot K_{a2})^2} + \dfrac{C \cdot \cdot K_{a1}}{K_{a1}\cdot [\ce{H_3O^+}] + [\ce{H_3O^+}]^2 + K_{a1} \cdot K_{a2}} \quad Eq.2
$$

The zero of this derivative is found at $[\ce{H_3O^+}] = \sqrt{K_{a1} \cdot K_{a2}}$, where is the maximum of $[\ce{AH^-}]$.

The buffer power (BP) can be defined $BP = \dfrac{dC_B}{dp \ce{H}} = -\dfrac{dC_A}{dp \ce{H}} = - 2.3 \cdot [\ce{H_3O^+}] \cdot \dfrac{d[\ce{HA^-}]}{d[\ce{H_3O^+}]} \quad Eq.3$

For example:

If $K_{a1} = 6.2  \times 10^{-8}$ and $K_{a2} = 4.8 \times 10^{-13}$ and C=0.1, the maximum oncentration of the specie $\ce{AH^-}$ is found at $[\ce{H_3O^+}] = \sqrt{6.2  \times 10^{-8} \cdot 4.8 \times 10^{-13}}  = 1.725 \times 10^{-10} \quad pH=9.76$

The curve that represents the buffer power, plotting the Eq.3, is:

[image]

In this way I can say that at maximum concentration of the amphiprotic substance the buffer power is zero. Is this statement true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the curve that represents the buffer capacity does not simply rely on one fraction of the whole system but on all species of the acid-base system it is not enough to only consider the derivative of $c(\ce{HA-})$.

You also have to take care of the other deprotonated species in your system. For the case of a diprotic acid this means that $c(\ce{A^2-})$ is also important albeit not much as you can see in the following figure.

[image: comparison of different simplifications onto the buffer capacity of a diprotic acid]
**Figure 1:** Buffer capacities for a diprotic acid with different amounts of assumptions taken into account – denoted by their plot labels. The lower graphs are zoomed versions of the upper graphs.

As you have come to the mass balance for $c(\ce{HA-})$ I don't have to show you how to come to the mass balance for $c(\ce{A^2-})$:
$$c(\ce{A^2-}) = \frac{c_0(\ce{H2A})~k_{a1}~k_{a2}}{c^2(\ce{H3O+})+c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+k_{a1}~k_{a2}}$$

This means that you have to derive the following equation:
$$C_B=\frac{c_0(\ce{H2A})~\left(c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+2~k_{a1}~k_{a2}\right)}{c^2(\ce{H3O+})+c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+2~k_{a1}~k_{a2}}$$
or if you want to include he self-ionization of water it has to be
$$C_B=\frac{k_W}{c(\ce{H3O+})}-c(\ce{H3O+})+\frac{c_0(\ce{H2A})~\left(c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+2~k_{a1}~k_{a2}\right)}{c^2(\ce{H3O+})+c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+2~k_{a1}~k_{a2}}$$

Let's derive (with the help of [D. D. van Slyke, *J. Biol. Chem.* **1922**, (*52*), 525-570](http://www.jbc.org/content/52/2/525.full.pdf) and Mathematica (or by hand if you've got time for that))
$$\beta=-\frac{\mathrm{dC_B}}{\mathrm{dpH}}=-\ln(10)~c(\ce{H3O+})~\left(\frac{\mathrm{d C_B}}{\mathrm{d}c(\ce{H3O+})}\right)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d C_B}}{\mathrm{d}c(\ce{H3O+})}=-\frac{k_W}{x}-1-\frac{c_0(\ce{H2A})~k_{a1}~c(\ce{H3O+})~(2~c(\ce{H3O+})+k_{a1})}{(c^2(\ce{H3O+})+c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+k_{a1}~k_{a2})^2}+\frac{c_0(\ce{H2A})~k_{a1}}{c^2(\ce{H3O+})+c(\ce{H3O+})~k_{a1}+k_{a1}~k_{a2}}$$

Using this final equation you should come up with plots like mine and see that the buffer capacity (for $c_0(\ce{H2A})=0.1~\ce{mol/L}$) at $\ce{pH}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ce{pK_{a1}}+\ce{pK_{a2}}\right)$ is not zero albeit not being very high.

- complete: $\beta=0.0014~\ce{mol/L}$
- complete w/o *water*: $\beta=0.0013~\ce{mol/L}$
- w/o $c(\ce{A^2-})$: $\beta=0.0001~\ce{mol/L}$
- w/o $c(\ce{A^2-})$ and *water*: $\beta=1.1 \cdot 10^{-10}~\ce{mol/L}$

So ... **is it correct to say that at maximum concentration of the amphiprotic substance the buffer capacity is zero?** No but for your to acidic constants it's nearly zero.

**But is it always zero at $c_\text{max}(\ce{HA^-})$?**

Let's look at those systems a little bit closer. Imagine a few systems and their corresponding buffer capacity curves with $pK_{a1}=4$ and $pK_{a2}$ values between 4 and 10 like in the following figure.

[image]

If you create a plot with the buffer capacity over $\frac{1}{2}\left(pK_{a1}+pK_{a2}\right)$ you would end up with something like this

[image]

What you can see now is that the buffer capacity at $c_\text{max}(\ce{HA-})$ depends clearly on the distance between both $pK_a$ values. If they are close together the buffer capacity at $c_\text{max}(\ce{HA-})$ is high and if $\Delta pK_a \approx 3$ the buffer capacity at $c_\text{max}(\ce{HA-})$ is nearly zero but never exactly zero.